# how to have the countdown trigger the function on if the if statement is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a video game project and I'm not too sure how to set up the if statement because I'm new to programming. I want to have a picture to pop up only after the countdown reaches its last digit or value.

I have the countdown code working great, but I need to have the picture to pop up at the right location. I'm not sure how to add the value towards this location with the if statement. Basically when I click a button it's switch the background image therefore It wouldn't be a very good game if a random picture pops up while I'm looking at the wrong background.

I feel like I should add a value whenever I click the button and the value will change whenever I click on a different button. I just don't know how to set up the value and have it equal to true.

Also is there a way to reset the countdown?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function countDown(secs,elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
    if(secs < 1) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';
        element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
        $("#black").show(0.1);
    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
  } 

  $(function(){
    $("#black").hide(0.01);
  })

  function goodtogo(){
    var good = true;
  }
</script>
```

```
<body>
  <div id="status"></div>

  <script>countDown(2, "status");</script>

  <img id="black" src="black1.jpg">
  <input  type="button" name="button" value="btn" onclick="goodtogo()">

</body>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` if for one iteration only. It's not performance wise thew way you're using `setTimeout` to create a continuous timer. If you want a timer for a countdown then you should use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.